# Visual Studio Community 2013 Update 4- designer doesn't load for WP app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I created a new project based on windows phone. when i try to open MainPage.xaml designer is not loading.

So far i tried

- Repairing Visual Studio
- Renewing Developer License
- Deleted this folder C:\Users{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache

but with no success. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Here is the error 
[image]

Thanks.

**Edit:** Error text

> System.Exception The package repository is corrupted.
>
> The package repository is corrupted.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String
>   applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary
>   environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory
>   factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo,
>   FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String
>   baseDirectory)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary
>   boundary)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary
>   boundary)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry&
>   entry)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo
>   culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.b__6()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: Please post the exact error message as text here.

Comment: Error message as text added to the post.

Comment: Have you tried create I new clean WP project, build it and see if designer works? With this we can know if a problem with VS or just your project.

Comment: Yes i tried. Actually this one is my fifth new empty project